# ASP.NET MVC getting the date from an implemented datepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I've implemented a working datepicker in a form, which is part of my asp.net mvc project.  However, I am having trouble obtaining the input value. For the other attributes in the form, I've been using Html.EditorFor(), but in this case, that does not work as it results in two text boxes appearing.  I've been unable to find a solution on the Internet and have looked for alternatives to EditorFor, but so far, have not found anything that works.

```
    <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("date:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no datepicker in the code shown above... it is just an input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution to this was to add a **name** attribute to the  tag, and pass this as a parameter to the controller method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming when you say "having trouble obtaining the input value," you mean that the the "date" param of the posted form's controller action isn't getting populated.

First try TextBoxFor(). If that doesn't work, you may need to use the name attribute in your input element.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not averse to using jQuery, you could just use this line:

```
var date = $('#date').val();
```

and then find a way to pass the javascript variable to your controller